# Why does sizeof(long long) return 8?

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm new to C. `sizeof(long)` returns 8 because the size of `long` is 8 bytes (4 bytes for a 32-bit OS).

But I wonder why `sizeof(long long)` is also 8. Shouldn't it be 16?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long));
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long long));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this article about C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) will give you some light? Pay attention to "..containing at least the...". It is compiler dependent.

Comment: Because on your platform, `long` is 8 and `long long` is 8.  On my platform, `int` is 8, `long` is 16, and `long long` is 32.  On someone elses platform, `int` might be 2, and `long` might be 4, and `long long` 8.  It varies by platform.  If you need a specific size, consider `std::int32_t` and `std::int64_t`.

Comment: @Eljay: You have a system where `long` is 16 and `long long` is `32`?!? What platform is that? I've basically never seen a system where `long long` is anything but `8`, `long` is the only one that varies much (being `4` on some systems, `8` on others). (Minor side-note: The question is about C, so no `std::` prefix)

Comment: IIRC, in the modern days, `long` is 4 bytes on Windows and 8 elsewhere. In case it's unclear, Eljay isn't speaking about real platforms, but just making a point.

Comment: In any event, Wikipedia has [an article on the various standards for data type sizes on 64 bit machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), if all you're looking for is "what will be what size, where".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I have to assume so, but they didn't phrase it that way, so I was curious if there was a real system like that (I've worked on some weird systems, where literally every type was eight bytes, including `char`, so I wasn't going to rule it out).

Comment: @ShadowRanger • it's not a real-real system yet, it's my work's in-house "garage" experimental system.  May or may not go anywhere.  (The question was previously tagged with `c++`.)

Comment: If these sizes were fixed, you wouldn't need the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I understand now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard does not require `long long` to be 16 bytes or to be wider than `long`.

In C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1, the standard requires `long long` to be able to represent numbers from −(2<sup>63</sup>−1) to +(2<sup>63</sup>−1). That requires at least 64 bits, so a `long long` must be at least 8 8-bit bytes (or, for example, 4 16-bit bytes). It is optional for a C implementation to make `long long` wider and support a larger range.

In 6.3.1.1 1, the standard requires the rank of `long long` (also known as `long long int`) to be greater than the rank of `long`. Due to the definition of “rank,” this means `long long` must have at least as much precision as `long`. (The precision of an integer type is the number of bits used to represent the value, not including the sign bit.) The standard does not require `long long` to have more precision than `long`; it can be equal.